# Spring Data JPA or spring hibernate which do i need to learn RN

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

from the above which should i learn or do I need to learn both then in which order 
im new to spring framework (about few days )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Hibernate is a JPA (specification) implementation.
2. A good way to learn Hibernate is to read the book "[Java Persistence in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate)" by Manning. It has 400 pages but teaches you everything there is to know.
3. Spring Data JPA builds ON TOP of Hibernate/JPA.
4. If you don't know Hibernate, you WILL get lost sooner or later with Spring Data, even if it makes things easier at the beginning for you.
5. A good article to help you get an overview of Hibernate/JPA/Spring Data etc: https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/java-databases-jdbc-hibernate-spring-data